# Telerik RadAsyncUpload UploadedFile Count is giving 0 when invalid file is uploaded

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i'm using `Telerik` `RadAsyncUpload`, I have kept a filter that `.csv` files are only allowed.

**In Designer:**

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="RadAsyncUpload1" runat="server" 
    EnableInlineProgress="true" UploadedFilesRendering="BelowFileInput" 
    HideFileInput="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID" MultipleFileSelection="Disabled"
    Localization-Select="Choose File" Width="100%"
    AllowedFileExtensions=".csv,.CSV" AllowedMimeTypes="application/csv"
    Filter="Others(*.csv;*.CSV)|*.csv;*.CSV" 
    MaxFileInputsCount="1">
    <FileFilters>
        <telerik:FileFilter Description="Others(*.csv;*.CSV)|*.csv;*.CSV"
            Extensions=".csv,.CSV" />
    </FileFilters>
    <Localization Select="Choose File" />
</telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

**In Code behind:**

```
var csv = new[] { ".csv" };
rauploadCSVFile.AllowedMimeTypes = csv;
rauploadCSVFile.AllowedFileExtensions = csv;
```

color indication when `.csv` file uploaded is green, non `.csv` file is red -- Okay i have no issues here.

but when non `.csv` file is uploaded, `RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count` returns 0, here the truth is that 1 invalid file is uploaded (non .csv file), that means count must be 1.

here i'm in a scenario:

**scenario 1:** when no file is given `RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count` returns 0, Now user display message: `File is mandatory`.

**scenario 2:** when non .csv file is given **still** `RadAsyncUpload1.UploadedFiles.Count` returns 0, Now user display message: `Only CSV files are allowed.`

**Question 1:** How can I achieve this?

**Question 2:** How to make RadAsyncUpload1 to show File Upload Dialog window's filter to display only 
**Other (*.csv)** instead of All Files(*.*),..etc

so that only .csv are shown in file system while choosing.

Comment: Remove the Filter from XAML and in code behind check if the file is of type CSV and then show the message.

Comment: If you are using a filter vale correctly you should only be able to upload .CSV file only

Comment: i kept as it is in above code which i hope are valid values but Could not able to achieve it!!!!

Comment: try this for the filter `Text Files (*.csv)|*.csv`

Comment: Hi user2526236, i tried FileFilters="Text Files (\*.csv)|\*.csv" for RadAsyncUpload but no use still filter in file upload dialog popup is showing All Files (\*.\*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi All Thanks for the support..

**Question 1 Answer:**
i figured it out, i removed AllowedFileExtensions in designer and code behind

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="RadAsyncUpload1" runat="server" EnableInlineProgress="true" 
        UploadedFilesRendering="BelowFileInput" HideFileInput="true" ClientIDMode="AutoID" 
    MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" Localization-Select="Choose File" 
    Width="100%" MaxFileInputsCount="1"
 OnClientFileSelected="OnClientFileSelected" OnClientAdded="OnClientAdded">
<Localization Select="Choose File" /> </telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

Now add the event

> OnClientFileSelected="OnClientFileSelected"

i'm maintaining those color indications in client side. those color indications are not colors they are .png images which are applied through the classes.

**classname (color) .extensionused**

ruUploadProgress (orange) .gif

ruUploadFailure (red) .png

ruUploadSuccess (green) .png

```
function OnClientFileSelected(sender, args) 
    {
        var fileExtention = args.get_fileName().substring(args.get_fileName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1, args.get_fileName().length);
        if (args.get_fileName().lastIndexOf('.') != -1)
        {
          var colorSpan = $('#<%=RadAsyncUpload1.ClientID%> ul li span span');
                            //checks if the extension is correct
          if (fileExtention.toLowerCase() == "csv")
          {
             colorSpan.removeClass("ruUploadFailure").addClass("ruUploadSuccess");
          }
          else
          {
             colorSpan.removeClass("ruUploadSuccess").addClass("ruUploadFailure");
          }
        }
    }
```

**Question 2 Answer:**

I found Solution for this too, just add event **OnClientAdded="OnClientAdded"**

Now in Java Script Add function:

```
function OnClientAdded(sender, args) {
    document.getElementById($('input[type=file]').attr('id')).accept = ".csv";
}
```

That's it Done..!!! :-) Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

The RadAsyncUpload blocks the invalid files from getting uploaded. You're going to need to do client-side validation to set the appropriate message because by the time it gets to the server, the file is not there since it's not a CSV. Take a look at Telerik's documentation at http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload-onclientvalidationfailed.html

They even provide an example of seeing if the file extension is in the allowed list.

Edit: To get your error strings from a database, you can add something like

```
var badFileName = '<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litBadFileName" />';
var noFile = '<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litNoFile" />';
```

Then populate those two literals on Page_Load from the database.

Comment: How do you see that? I've never worked with their WPF/Silverlight controls, and as you notice this was only tagged C#.

Comment: Hi dman2306, Thank you so much for replying but i'm getting the validation messages from database where my application is language independent. so is there any possibility to validate at server side?

Comment: Great idea and still doable. What I'd do is get the error messages from the database in Page_Load or a similar event, and store them in JavaScript variables. Then you can set the appropriate one.

Comment: Okay i will try and let know you by posting here.

Comment: Hi dman2306, can i get the same functionality on client side vice versa?? i.e
 i'm removing the AllowedFileExtensions in both designer and code behind.

now the color indication is always green. So now can i check .csv extension in client side and for non .csv file make that color to red?

Comment: If you remove the AllowedFileExtensions, then the OnClientValidationFailed event will never fire. You want AllowedFileExtensions to be csv, then add an OnClientValidationFailed handler to display your message.

Comment: Why should i depend on OnClientValidationFailed event? 
i can call ChangeColor(sender, args) JQuery function through OnClientFileUploading="ChangeColor"
 But what i need here is how to change it accordingly in client side, i mean the JQuery code to do so??

Comment: Sorry, I think you need to post your new code. Nothing you or I have talked about so far has had an OnClientFileUploading event. If all you want to do is change the color of some element $("#theIDOfTheElement").css('color','red') will do it. Is that what you're asking?